# Joomla - create custom rewrite rules

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, components, joomla3.0

I developed a Joomla website which is like a directory. People have their profile in the site and I created a component called com_profile to display their profile when passing the id. So for the following URL it is displaying the profile now.

http:///index.php?option=com_profile&id=100

I need to change the url so when a user type like this "http:///service_providers/100" it will show the profile.

How can I do this? I tried different ways in htaccess nothing helped. :(

Answer (score 0):

Add this to your apache configuration or htaccess file:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^service_providers/([a-zA-Z0-9-z\-]+)$ index.php?option=com_profile&id=$1
```

Make sure that modrewrite is enabled.  If it's not, enable it via cli by typing a2en modrewrite

Comment: Thanks. But it is not working. Previously when I type the url it went to 404 page but now it is not going to 404. But displaying the home page. 

I typed this url <mysite>/service_providers/193. It shows the home page still. When I type <mysite>/option=com_profile&id=193 it is showing the correct profile.

Comment: Sorry. It seems working. I think some resrictions in my component redirecting back to home page. Thanks a lot. I will check and fix it.